# How to update the table with large size update query in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have large size of update query it is 320 Kb sql file. i can't execute that query/file.please help me i am using oracle 10g.only one column have that bulk data i used CLOB data type to the table.

Comment: it contain encrypted values. if i execute that file it shows internal error than automatically the 10g closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to execute it this way on Unix/Linux:

```
save the query to x.sql
sqlplus myuser/mypass@mydb
@x
```

If this does not work please include the relevant error codes and messages.